# Custom rules in SCOM 2007

Tags: windows, sql-server, monitoring, scom

Our networking department uses Microsoft's System Center Operations Manager 2007 (formerly MOM) to monitor servers. We want to check if a particular SQL Server database is being updated (basically if there are any rows with the current date in a particular table). I can write the SQL query with no problems, but one of our networking guys wants a VBScript to use with an alert-generating rule.

I have an example of this, but was hoping that there's a cleaner way than VBScript.

- Is there an existing module for this?
- Can you write custom rules (or whatever's appropriate) in C#?
- Can you write them in PowerShell?
- Any examples/links on the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use OpsMgr then you will need to use VBscript in order to build such a rule.

there may be a way to build some POSH scripts, but i haven't looked into that possibility. doing so would require something outside of OpsMgr to execute the POSH script on a regular basis.

i am curious as to why OpsMgr is your preferred solution versus other options. could you explain more about your environment? you might find it easier to use PBM, for example, or even a trigger.

Comment: Thank you - I did bite the bullet and modify an example script. Monitoring is controlled by our Networking group (I'm in the Development group) and I have little say in the choice of solutions.